# Does sinch SDK use implicit intent in their service?

Tags: android, sinch, android-implicit-intent

In brief I just want a simple answer for my question.
does sinch SDK use implicit intent in their service ?

Comment: Why don't you read the docs? https://www.sinch.com/docs/android/user-guide/

Comment: There is nothing there saying anything about it, so I'm trying to ask one of their developers about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Sinch SDK does not contain any implicit intents nor does it have it's own service. It's up to the developer to implement a service.